# Merge pandas data frame based on specific conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below

df1:

```
ID   Job   Salary
1    A     100
2    B     200
3    B     20
4    C     150
5    A     500
6    A     600
7    A     200
8    B     150
```

df2:

```
    ID      Type        Status       Age
    1       2           P            23
    2       1           P            28
    8       1           F            33
    4       3           P            48
    14      1           F            23
    11      2           P            28
    16      2           F            23
    41      3           P            38
```

df3:

```
ID   T_Type       Amount
1    K            20
2    L            -50
1    K            30
3    K            5
1    K            100
2    L            -50
1    L            -30
25   K            500
1    K            20
4    L            -80
19   K            30
2    K            -5
```

Explanation About the data

```
ID is the primary key of df1.

ID is the primary key of df2.

df3 does not have any primary key.
```

From the above, I would like to prepare below dfs.

```
1. IDs which are in df1 and df2.

Expected output1:

ID   Job   Salary   
1    A     100
2    B     200
4    C     150
8    B     150
```

2. IDs which are there in df1 and not in df2

output2:

```
ID   Job   Salary
3    B     20
5    A     500
6    A     600
7    A     200
```

3. IDs which are there in df1 and df3

output3:

```
ID   Job   Salary
1    A     100
2    B     200
3    B     20
4    C     150

4. IDs which are there in df1 and not in df3.
```

output4:

```
ID   Job   Salary
5    A     500
6    A     600
7    A     200
8    B     150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> # 1. IDs which are in df1 and df2.
>>> df1[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
   ID Job  Salary
0   1   A     100
1   2   B     200
3   4   C     150
7   8   B     150

>>> # 2. IDs which are there in df1 and not in df2    
>>> df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
   ID Job  Salary
2   3   B      20
4   5   A     500
5   6   A     600
6   7   A     200

>>> # 3. IDs which are there in df1 and df3
>>> df1[df1['ID'].isin(df3['ID'])]
   ID Job  Salary
0   1   A     100
1   2   B     200
2   3   B      20
3   4   C     150

>>> # 4. IDs which are there in df1 and not in df3.
>>> df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df3['ID'])]
   ID Job  Salary
4   5   A     500
5   6   A     600
6   7   A     200
7   8   B     150
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your expected results aren't any merges, but rather
**selections**, based on whether *df1.ID* is (or is not) in *ID* column
of the second DataFrame.

To get your expected results, run the following commands:

```
result_1 = df1[df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)]
result_2 = df1[~df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)]
result_3 = df1[df1.ID.isin(df3.ID)]
result_4 = df1[~df1.ID.isin(df3.ID)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I would like to accept all the answers